# datastructure to maintain time window of values?

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures

I'm working on a problem where I need to maintain a ten second time window of points.  As new points come in they add to end of queue and as time goes on points that are older than ten seconds so leave front of queue.  Queue can get pretty big , say 1000 or more elements.

The interesting part is I also need to access elements in middle of quickly like say the first element older than 3 seconds ago. Doing this fast is the difficult part.

Note that queue is always sorted.

I thought about sorted array but that is slow to remove elements from front.  List is slow to search.

Am doing this in c++,  but any language welcome.

Comment: What is wrong with a simple `std::set`? How fast do you need this to be?

Comment: Do the points arrive uniformly in time?

Comment: std::deque + binary search might be worth thinking about. It might help if you gave a more precise definition of what queries must be supported.

Comment: Use an array two or three times bigger than the maximum number of points you'll need to store at any given time.  Keep 'front' and 'back' pointers; when the 'back' pointer wants to go past the end of the array, move everything to the beginning of the array.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm working on a problem where I need to maintain a ten second time window of points. As new points come in they add to end of queue and as time goes on points that are older than ten seconds so leave front of queue. Queue can get pretty big , say 1000 or more elements.

1000 elements does not seem large in any way, so I don't see what the issue is there. Actual timing requirements would be more useful.

> Note that queue is always sorted.

Sorted by what? Time? Since time seems to be the index itself and it's a FIFO, this seems to be the case by definition.

> I thought about sorted array but that is slow to remove elements from front.

Why does it need to be sorted additionally? How slow is it, and how fast does it need to be? What implementation are you using? If you know an upper bound on the number of points, why not just use a circular buffer?

> List is slow to search.

What search method are you using? What does its implementation look like? How slow is it? How fast does it need to be? Is anything known in advance about the nature of the search that could help speed it up? Is a binary search not fast enough?